# Tesseract traineddata path

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two

I am trying to use tesseract-ocr in my android app. When I am trying to init() I get IllegalArgumentException because in this folder there is no 'tessdata' dir! Here is my project structure. [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GOWG.jpg)

Here I used InputStream and cacheDir:

```
private String getDirPath() {
    File f = new File(getCacheDir()+"/tessdata/");
    if (!f.exists()) try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { Log.e("error", e.toString()); }
    Log.i("wtf", f.getPath());
    return getCacheDir();
}
```

To init the Tesseract I have to pass 2 arguments - path to dir which contains directory 'tessdata' and second one is traineddata.
Any ideas?

Comment: have you add read files permission?

Comment: Yeah I added them in them beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to your app's raw asset files that way. Try using [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) instead.

Comment: Here! I edited my post with other way to get dir path.

Comment: You edited your post to make it a completely different question. Please don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

The path to your assets is

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/")
 String dataPath = path.toString();
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I used this code but I got the same exception​.